# Persistance datalayer in EF core ,dynamic EF. Separate EF from models

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-model-builder

I want to separate EF layer from my model .

I need a EF Builder to send my model to it like this(I found this code for mongodb but i need for EF core) :

```
        builder.AddMongo();
        builder.AddMongoRepository<Cart>("Carts");
        builder.AddMongoRepository<Customer>("Customers");
        builder.AddMongoRepository<Product>("Products");
```

The above code is inside startup file  .

I pass the parameters from `applicationsetting.json` file as you can see :

```
 "mongo": {
    "connectionString": "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    "database": "customers-service",
    "seed": false
  },
```

Here is the mongo sample code :

[image]

```
public static class Extensions
    {
        public static void AddMongo(this ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Register(context =>
            {
                var configuration = context.Resolve<IConfiguration>();
                var options = configuration.GetOptions<MongoDbOptions>("mongo");

                return options;
            }).SingleInstance();

            builder.Register(context =>
            {
                var options = context.Resolve<MongoDbOptions>();

                return new MongoClient(options.ConnectionString);
            }).SingleInstance();

            builder.Register(context =>
            {
                var options = context.Resolve<MongoDbOptions>();
                var client = context.Resolve<MongoClient>();
                return client.GetDatabase(options.Database);

            }).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            builder.RegisterType<EFDbInitializer>()
                .As<IEFDbInitializer>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            builder.RegisterType<MongoDbSeeder>()
                .As<IEFDbSeeder>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        }

        public static void AddMongoRepository<TEntity>(this ContainerBuilder builder, string collectionName)
            where TEntity : IIdentifiable
            => builder.Register(ctx => new EFRepository<TEntity>(ctx.Resolve<IMongoDatabase>(), collectionName))
                .As<IMongoRepository<TEntity>>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
```

My question is :is there any solution for EF like mongo ?

Every part of code for mongoDb is available.

Comment: You'll need to clarify what you mean by "solution for EF like mongo"? What is that you are looking to get from EF?

Comment: @trailmax here is the microservices sample code that uses Mongodb in commonlayer i just want to replace this with EF https://github.com/devmentors/DNC-DShop

Comment: As already been said, Mongo is a database. EF is access layer. One can't be replaced by the other. Are you looking to move your data from MongoDB to SQL Server? Are you looking to access MongoDB via EF? Your link is not making your question more clear - a tutorial on how to build microservices, I don't see how that is related.

Comment: @trailmax i want to use sqlserver and access the data using EF

Comment: @trailmax in fact i have several microservices that each of them has its database , i want to use Sqlserver with EF orm ,and each microservice works with its database

Comment: @EhsanAkbar I have same issue. Did you got the solution?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I believe there is a little confusion :

- [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/what-is-mongodb) is a database
- [Entity Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) is an ORM. It allows you to access to data in a storage

That said, you can use EF Core with [several data storages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/), such as MongoDB or SQL Server for instance.

To want a separated layer between your entities (Data Access Layer) and your business model is a good practice, and should be encouraged. 
Because the topic is wide, and because lot of documentations and tutorials exists and the subject, I prefer to give you some links rather than to give you a complete architecture.

You can check [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-implemenation-entity-framework-core) from Microsoft to see the related layers, and what they should contains.

Also, I advise you to consult [this github repo](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture), which provide tons of clean architectures based on .net core.

Feel free to dig a bit into those links, they are providing a lot of precious informations.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you .Could you please take a look at https://github.com/devmentors/DNC-DShop, the common layer

Comment: I just need a separate DLL or module to pass my entities and connection string to create my database

Comment: @EhsanAkbar The "module" you are talking about is just an implementation of a Data Access Layer using EF Core. If you like the way this "module" is coded, you just need to replace some parts to be compliant with the data storage you want to use. I cannot take each file and edit it to make it works for your case. I don't know what data storage you wanna use, I don't know what entities your repository should contains, I don't know if you need to seed the database, etc. Please, dig a bit into the code you found and what I provided in my answer. You have everything to make it works. :)