# Passing generic DBset entities to DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, generics, .net-core, dbcontext, dbset

Here is my dbcontext

```
public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    //dbset 1
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    //dbset 2
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

I want to pass my models i mean `Customer` and `order` outside `MyDbContext` .something like this :

```
public partial class MyDbContext<T> : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<T> <T>{ get; set; }

}
```

And a function to get the list of entities to add to my context like this

```
addEntityToDbContext(Customer)
addEntityToDbContext(Orders)
```

Is it possible?

I am using EF Core .

Comment: Why you need so?

Comment: @TanvirArjel because i use microservices in my project and each of them has its own database,and i want to create a public EF for each of them

Comment: DbSet<T> is a generic class already. What you ask is the DbContext class itself. Microservices have nothing to do with what you ask, nor do multiple databases. You can change the connection string of a context at runtime.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but each of microservices has its model and database .

Comment: here is my question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56273847/persistance-datalayer-in-ef-core-dynamic-ef-separate-ef-from-models

Comment: So use different contexts and different connection strings. Load the connection strings at runtime.  That's what DbContext already supports. There's nothing "dynamic" about this.

Comment: @EhsanAkbar a DbContext is a Unit of Work, not a model of the entire database. Even a simple web application can have different contexts for different modules/functionality. In fact, in a moderately complex application the same business entity may have to be represented using different classes. The `User` in a forum's post isn't the same as the `User` in the same forum's authentication system

Comment: @EhsanAkbar and speaking of services (micro is just branding), [your data model is not your object model is not your resource model is not your message model](https://codeopinion.com/web-api-resource-model-isnt-data-model/).

Comment: Don't try to be generic everywhere on any cost. It not worth it,  especially in microservices.

Comment: @Fabio you know i am following the D-Shop pattern.https://github.com/devmentors/DNC-DShop,In this project the mongodb is separated from all microservices and each microservices send its classes to mongoextenstion to create the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is? But DbContext has a generic DbSet method already built in?

```
    public virtual DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class => 
(DbSet<TEntity>)((IDbSetCache)this).GetOrAddSet(DbContextDependencies.SetSource, typeof(TEntity));
```

Comment: Thank you.could you please give me a sample

Comment: Can you add some clarity to the question then please? Its not entirely clear what you're actually asking for

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56273847/persistance-datalayer-in-ef-core-dynamic-ef-separate-ef-from-models

Comment: @EhsanAkbar that question doesn't clarify anything. The *answer* explains that the question confuses different concepts

Comment: in fact i want to work with my context like a nuget and i pass my entities and my connection string to create my database .

Comment: Sorry @EhsanAkbar, it appears that I'm not making myself clear. Your question isnt detailed enough. You need to change the question so that we can answer it. What specifically are you asking?

Comment: @EhsanAkbar the context has no similarity to NuGet. It's a Unit of Work. It's not a "Repository" either. A DbSet is a *higher-level* concept than a simple Repository. The connection string can be changed at runtime. I suspect you are confused by using the wrong terms, or perhaps by following a "tutorial" that uses trendy words instead of actually explaining anything? A "microservice" can be implemented as a single Web API controller with a single context. Its connection string can easily change at runtime - just pass a different one to its constructor!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos did you see th Dshop sample ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in d shop the database is mongo but each domain and microservice sends its entities and connection to the mongoRepository to generate the database

Comment: @EhsanAkbar that's a built-in feature of EF Core. It doesn't need any special treatment. I'd **strongly** advise you to take care when following "courses" from companies that can't even be bothered to use a valid SSL certificate. That site is full of buzzwords and the "repository" classes are the same generic repository **antipattern* that plagues beginners

Comment: I think this question is more about confusion and misunderstanding than an actual coding problem..

Comment: @EhsanAkbar there's no need for "distributed .NET Core". .NET was used to create distributed, service-based applications from day 1, back in 2002.

Comment: @EhsanAkbar I'd also *strongly* suggest following the courses of a reputable training company like Pluralsights or Wintellect. Pluralsight course authors are some of the best known authors and bloggers in the .NET world. You can get 3 months free access to all of their courses through Microsoft's also free Visual Studio Dev Essentials program